# Loop through async callbacks in non-blocking sequence

Tags: javascript, loops, nonblocking

Hitting a wall here trying to get this to work - the `console.log` output should be `0, 1, 2, 3`. It should basically loop through the array and call the functions in sequence in a non-blocking way (waiting for `done()` if passed in):

```
var array = [

  function(done) {
    setTimeout(function() {
       console.log(0);
      done();
    }, 2000);
  },

  function(done) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(1);
      done();
    }, 200);
  },

  function() {
    // This one is synchronous and doesn't need
    // to use done()
    console.log(2);
  },

  function(done) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(3);
      done();
    }, 70);
  }

];
```

I don't mind if the solutions are using generators, or Promises, or perhaps something else. I was thinking the function could be wrapped something along the lines of:

```
function fnWrapper(fn) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    if (fn.length >= 1) {
      // If the done callback is passed in.
      fn(resolve);
    } else {
      fn();
      resolve();
    }
  });
}

array.reduce((promise, fn) => promise.then(fnWrapper(fn)), Promise.resolve());
```

http://codepen.io/ferahl/pen/wGoRZN?editors=0010

But so far my attempts to loop through this with a generator or promise/reduce are very broken. Any ideas? Thanks.

Update: PS I can't control what async method will be used to call `done()` in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that in order for my promises to execute in sequence, I needed to return a function which returned a promise in the `then` (rather than passing the promise itself into it):

```
function fnWrapper(fn) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    if (fn.length >= 1) {
      // If the done callback is passed in.
      fn(resolve);
    } else {
      fn();
      resolve();
    }
  });
}

array.reduce((promise, fn) => promise.then(() => fnWrapper(fn)), Promise.resolve());
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/ferahl/pen/wGoRZN?editors=0010

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution using promises (and `Array.prototype.reduce` to run the functions in series):

```
// promise version of setTimeout
function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}

var array = [
  function() {
    return delay(2000)
      .then(() => console.log(0));
  },

  function() {
    return delay(200)
      .then(() => console.log(1));
  },

  function() {
    console.log(2);
  },

  function() {
    return delay(70)
      .then(() => console.log(3));
  }
];

array.reduce((promise, fn) => promise.then(fn), Promise.resolve());
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/FullR/pen/eZBbLN?editors=0010)

Comment: This is a lovely solution thanks, the problem is that those functions are written by users and I can't control what async method they're using

Comment: Is the async method expected to be consistent? Your best bet may be to just pick a method and explain to your users which method of async your API expects.

Comment: Yeah you might be right, I'll give it some thought and accept if I can't think of something

Comment: You could also try wrapping the user functions to create a consistent API. Here's my attempt a wrapper function that can handle either last argument callback functions or promise returning functions: http://codepen.io/FullR/pen/jqVXJg?editors=0010

Comment: Yeah I was basically trying to do that http://codepen.io/ferahl/pen/wGoRZN?editors=0010 but you actually got yours working, I'll have a read tomorrow and accept - thanks for the help